# javascript regular expression to match ASCII 

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like help on building a regular expression to find ACII codes

So far I came up with this, http://jsfiddle.net/G7cab/

but as you'll notice I'm not capturing all the groups that match this expression.

I would appreciate some help
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: from what I can see you are trying to match HTML entities -- are you trying to remove them from the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a shorter form for (what I understood you) wanted to do based on your fiddle:

```
var s = '&#39; &#94; hola tio, que tal estas? &#33;'
          .replace(/(&#\d+;)/g,
             function(a){
              return String.fromCharCode(a.substr(2,a.length-3));
             }
           );
 alert(s); //=> ' ^ hola tio, que tal estas? !
```

So, the regular expression here is `/(&#\d+;)/g`

By the way, `&[#num][name];` are called (numeric) [html entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). The code here is only working for such entities (so, not for named html entities like `&copy;` (©) etc.). If you want to do that (and within a browser), use the method from the elected answer in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks to all for the answers , much appreciated! (and sorry for the confusion about HTML entities)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to unescape HTML Entities. It was discussed on SO:

[Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)